# Deserialization into a list and drawing them again

Tags: c#, deserialization

I serialized a class (Shape Class) into my own file extension (.seal file).

```
 public void Serialization()
    {
            //Open the File Dialog for Saving
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            //Custome File Extension
            save.Filter = "Seal Creator File (*.seal)|*.seal";
            save.DefaultExt = ".seal";
            save.AddExtension = true;

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Serializers
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Shape>));
                //XmlSerializer ser2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
                FileStream file = File.Create(save.FileName);
                //Serialization process for the Class and DataSet
                ser.Serialize(file, draw._shapes);
                //ser2.Serialize(file, dataTable);
                file.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Saved");
            }
    }
```

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfShape xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Shape>
    <size>
      <Width>480</Width>
      <Height>415.6922</Height>
    </size>
    <location>
      <X>10</X>
      <Y>12</Y>
    </location>
    <radius>0</radius>
    <type>triangle</type>
    <width>480</width>
    <height>415.6922</height>
    <strokeThickness>2</strokeThickness>
    <color />
    <userDefinedWidth>0</userDefinedWidth>
    <userDefinedHeight>0</userDefinedHeight>
    <userDefinedStroke>0</userDefinedStroke>
  </Shape>
</ArrayOfShape>
```

Now what I want to do, is to store the values again into a list and redraw them in the picturebox.

```
    public void DrawAllShapes(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Shape shape in _shapes)
        {
            switch (shape.type)
            {
                case Shape.ShapeType.rectangle:
                    shape.DrawRectangle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.width , shape.height, e.Graphics, shape.radius);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.square:
                    shape.DrawSquare(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics, shape.radius);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.circle:
                    shape.DrawCircle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.width , shape.height , e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.ellipse:
                    shape.DrawEllipse(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.triangle:
                    shape.DrawTriangle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.width, e.Graphics, shape.radius);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

**Deserialization:**

```
public void Deserialize(StreamReader file)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Shape> shape_ = new List<Shape>();
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(shape_.GetType());
            List<Shape> shape = (List<Shape>)ser.Deserialize(file);
            shape_ = shape;
            shape_.ForEach(draw._shapes.Add);
            file.Close();
            pictureBox_Canvass.Invalidate();
            Debug.WriteLine(shape_.Count.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Catching the Error
            String innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null)? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
            Debug.WriteLine(innerMessage);
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
    }
```

Edit: Added Deserialization Method. NOw it seems like I can get the list of shapes, but I still can' redraw them in the pictureBox.

Comment: How did you serialize your file?

Comment: I like that you left out the serialization code but included drawing code.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Looks like you're serializing two separate root elements into a single file.  Strictly speaking, that file is no longer well-formed XML because a well-formed XML document must have exactly one [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).

Comment: So how do I serialize a dataTable and  a class into one root? @dbc

Comment: If you need to serialize 2 different objects and store the result, you can do 2 things: store the objects in different files, or create an object that contains both objects, anyway, taking a look at you serialized file, seems that something is not working as expected because there is only a List<Shape>

Comment: Yes @ÓscarAndreu, I exclude the other serialization (DataTable), because no, what I wanted is to draw the shapes in the xml file. How to do that?

Comment: Doing that you are giving us wrong information, could you please put the complete file or at least a meaningful part of it?, how do you do the deserialization?

Comment: I'm asking how to deserialize it, so I don't have any methods yet. @ÓscarAndreu

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu edited the question, I tried deserializing but it won't draw.

Comment: This is a different problem, search about how to redraw elements in windows forms, in the old times was something related to the thread that is executing the redraw, and the invalidate doesn't works, right now don't know if there is an improvement.

Comment: By the way, this line  shape_ = shape; is useless, avoid this, use shape directly and if is a collection, as it is, use plural names.